# How to add category summation using vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code that outputs a list of numbers. This list could vary by every execution. Therefore the number of rows and position of empty cells could change by each run.
What I need here is to insert the summation of white cells ( correspond to each product category) into the following green cell at column B (Aval.Qnty). This is showed in the below picture.

[image]

Is there any way to do that through piece of vba code?

Comment: It will be easier for others to help you figure out where you're stuck if you edit you question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Add Subtotals

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddSubTotals()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    If rCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' not enough data
    
    With rg.Columns(2)
        
        Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Value
        
        Dim r As Long
        Dim sTotal As Double
        
        For r = 2 To rCount
            If IsEmpty(Data(r, 1)) Then
                .Rows(r).Value = sTotal
                sTotal = 0
            Else
                If IsNumeric(Data(r, 1)) Then
                    sTotal = sTotal + Data(r, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

(The solution below is not vba but excel formula. It will help you I think.)

1. You can use the formula at C2 and extend this formula to the bottom to get the sums of product categories:

> =IF(LEFT(A2,3)=LEFT(A1,3),B2+C1,B2)

You need to only consider the cells next to the blank cells at column C for sums of product categories.

2. You can use the formula at D2 and extend this formula to the bottom to get total sum

> =IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="X",C2+D1,IF(ISNUMBER(D1),D1,0))

You need to only consider the bottom cell at column D for total sum.

Here is the formulas and result:

[Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSoTS.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66gZ1.png)

You can analyze the formulas for how it works.